# Revit API: create appearance asset for material

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to set an appearance color for a newly created material. To do that, I need to create an `AppearanceAssetElement` for that material.

Here I run into trouble - to create an `AppearanceAssetElement`, I need to have an existing asset. However, when inspecting all existing materials, none of them has any appearance asset attached (note: my entire project document is created via API in the same transaction; maybe that causes the problem?).

How can I create the `AppearanceAssetElement` in my case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question on the Revit API forum that is solved:

[Revit API Forum question](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/creating-materials-with-appearance-asset/td-p/8332858)

And some useful links on the building coder:

[Material texture path](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/10/material-texture-path.html)

[Modidfying material visual apperearence](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/11/modifying-material-visual-appearance.html)

An extract from the building coder on changing color:

```
   using( AppearanceAssetEditScope editScope
    = new AppearanceAssetEditScope( document ) )
  {
    Asset editableAsset = editScope.Start( assetElem.Id );
    AssetPropertyDoubleArray4d genericDiffuseProperty
      = editableAsset["generic_diffuse"]
        as AssetPropertyDoubleArray4d;
    genericDiffuseProperty.SetValueAsColor( color );
    editScope.Commit( true );
  }
```